# how to delete a message

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, inbox

I try to delete a message from my inbox.
But i get 100 invailid parameter exception
I use csharp sdk

```
FacebookWebClient fbw = new FacebookWebClient(accesstoken);
fbw.Delete("/userid_messageid");
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to delete inbox messages with current API's. Permission about inbox is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Did your app create that message in the first place?  If not, then you cannot delete it.